# UseEffect, axios and setState. Why is not reseting this state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am trying to update my state (initial state) from an empty array if no type for searching books (through google's api books query).

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (search === "") {
      setBooks([])
      return 
    } 
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios({
          url: `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${search}&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_GOOGLE_FAKE}`
        })
        setBooks(response.data.items)

      } catch (exception) {
        console.log(exception)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [search, ])
```

I handle some aproachs (that works), but I am wondering why I cannot change array of books to empty as initial state.

My solutions to left array empty:

```
  let filteredBooks = []

  if(search !== '') {
    filteredBooks = books.map(e => e)
  }
```

Here full code, and at the end, console.log in a browser:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Book from './components/Book';
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (search === "") {
      setBooks([])
      return 
    } 
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios({
          url: `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${search}&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_GOOGLE_FAKE}`
        })
        setBooks(response.data.items)

      } catch (exception) {
        console.log(exception)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [search, ])


  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value)
  }

  let filteredBooks = []

  if(search !== '') {
    filteredBooks = books.map(e => e)
  } 

  console.log(search, 'search...');
  console.log(filteredBooks, 'filteredBooks...');
  console.log(books, 'books...');


  return (
    <div className="App">

      <header className="App-header">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>Your menu</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <section>

        <article>
          <div className="input-group searchListBooks">
            <div className="form-outline">
              <input onChange={handleSearch} type="search" id="form1" className="form-control" value={search} />
              <label className="form-label" htmlFor="form1">Search</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>

        <article>
          <header>
            <h2>Books</h2>
          </header>
          <ul className="listBook">
            {
              search.length === 0
                ?
                <p>Write some text</p>
                :
                filteredBooks.map(book => (
                  <Book {...book} key={book.id} />
                ))
            }
          </ul>
        </article>

      </section>
      <aside>
        <h2>About section</h2>
        <p>Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      </aside>

      <footer>
        <p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Log, where you can see how books state is still filled from query...

```
[] filteredBooks...
**(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] books...**
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where are you resetting the state even? The code looks like it just reads the value of the search and then reacts to it, no reset involved.

Comment: @BillerBuilder if (search === "") {
      setBooks([])
      return 
    }

Comment: This only checks for empty search field, so unless the input is reset, it won't reset by itself.

Comment: I want this behaviour: if user write some titles, do the query, and when user leave empty search bar or delete search bar, state must be empty

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchBooks = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${search}&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_GOOGLE_FAKE}`
      );

      console.log(res.data); // log first and if it was valid format
      setBooks(res.data.items);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    if (search !== "") {
      fetchBooks();
    } else {
      setBooks([]);
    }
  };
}, [search]);
```

Comment: thanks you, it works, but i don't understand why first if it is not working.

Comment: @titoih you made this hard for yourself sometime, a little console.log saves a lot of time before setting the state log it if it was the data you wanted then set the state and use that data

Comment: I want to not do the query if user delete what typed in search bar

Comment: Here is the thing that you want, just fetch the date when ever user typed in something
````
  if (search !== "") {
      fetchBooks();
    } else {
      setBooks([]);
    }
````